# How to find the controls in-game of Arena?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

Easy question, I just want to know if there is anyway to view the controls in-game while playing the Elder Scrolls I: Arena? I [already know what the controls are](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Arena:Controls), but I just want to know if there is any way that was programmed to access them in-game.

It may be impossible, because they might have only included the controls in the game manual (which I don't have), but I'm hoping that is only if everyone is 100% sure there is no way to see them while playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck here.

Neither the [manual](http://tes.riotpixels.com/arena/files/arena-manual.pdf) nor the game itself mention a way to display key bindings. And, unlike its successor Daggerfall, there is no key remap function that can be used to look up keys.

Comment: Oh well. At least the manual you linked to (thanks) gives a list of the keys on pg 37. Thanks anyway!